# Junção de bases com ids repetidos nas duas bases

Tags: r

Tenho duas bases de dados, uma base de cirurgias, com o prontuário do paciente e a data de realização da cirurgia e uma base de movimentações. Movimentações tem uma coluna de prontuário e data de internação do paciente, e data da alta, preciso juntar essas bases, mas como um mesmo prontuário pode ter mais de um valor nas duas bases, não tenho nenhum identificador único, então a estratégia é a seguinte, Tenho que pegar a data de realização da cirurgia na base de cirurgia e com essa data verificar, se essa data está no intervalo da base de movimentações, que é entre data da alta - data de internação do paciente, se a data da cirurgia estiver nesse intervalo, preciso contabilizar o valor da qtde de cirurgias no data frame movimentações(cada linha em cirurgias é uma cirurgia realizada naquela data, alguém pode me ajudar como fazer isso em R? a base de dados tem 400 mil registros. aqui está um exemplo simplificado para um paciente.

```r
dados <- c(
  50000, "2016-09-29 13:39:00", "2016-09-30 16:00:00",
  50000, "2016-10-06 14:50:00", "2016-10-08 09:00:00",
  50000, "2017-08-02 16:27:00", "2017-08-03 11:30:00",
  50000, "2017-08-08 08:52:00", "2017-08-09 20:10:00",
  50000, "2017-09-05 14:17:00", "2017-09-11 08:20:00",
  50000, "2018-05-21 17:46:00", "2018-05-24 17:50:00"
)


matriz <- matrix(dados, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)


movimentacoes <- as.data.frame(matriz)


colnames(movimentacoes) <- c("Prontuario", "DataInternacao", "HoraAlta")

movimentacoes$Prontuario <- as.integer(movimentacoes$Prontuario)
movimentacoes$DataInternacao <- as.POSIXct(movimentacoes$DataInternacao)
movimentacoes$HoraAlta <- as.POSIXct(movimentacoes$HoraAlta)



cirurgias = 
  data.frame(
    prontuario = rep(50000,3),
    data_realiza = as.Date(c('2017-09-07','2016-09-29','2017-09-11')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Se para cada número de prontuário os períodos de internação são únicos (i.e., sem sobreposição), pode usar a combinação `Prontuario` e `DataInternacao` ou `DataAlta` como identificadores. Com isso:

- Usar um *non-equi join* (*rolling* ou condicional) para incluir a data de internação ou alta nos dados de cirurgia (para referência, [Rui Barradas propôs uma união condicional usando sqldf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/586430/117168));
- Contar o número de ocorrências (cirurgias) por período de internação para cada prontuário;
- Juntar essa informação aos dados de movimentações.

Vou modificar seu exemplo para ter mais de um código de prontuário e para facilitar a visualização. No caso dos seus dados originais, faça os ajustes necessários (padronizar o nome da coluna "Prontuario" nos dois *data.frames* e converter/criar colunas de internação e alta apenas com a data (p.e. com `as.Date`).

```
movimentacoes <- read.csv(text =
  "Prontuario, DataInternacao, DataAlta
   50000,      2016-09-29,     2016-09-30
   50000,      2017-08-08,     2017-08-09
   50000,      2017-09-05,     2017-09-11
   50000,      2018-05-21,     2018-05-24
   61111,      2016-10-18,     2016-10-29
   61111,      2017-03-14,     2017-04-01
   61111,      2018-06-21,     2018-07-02",
  colClasses = c("integer", "Date", "Date"))

cirurgias <- read.csv(text =
  "Prontuario, DataCirurgia
   50000,      2016-09-29
   50000,      2017-09-07
   50000,      2017-09-11
   61111,      2016-10-20
   61111,      2017-03-18
   61111,      2017-03-25
   61111,      2017-03-29",
  colClasses = c("integer", "Date"))
```

### Com dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

resultado <- cirurgias %>%
  left_join(movimentacoes,
    join_by(Prontuario == Prontuario,
            DataCirurgia >= DataInternacao,
            DataCirurgia <= DataAlta)) %>%
  summarize(n.cirurgias = n(),
    .by = c("Prontuario", "DataInternacao")) %>%  # ou DataAlta; como cada combinação é única, não faz diferença
  right_join(movimentacoes) %>%
  mutate(n.cirurgias = ifelse(is.na(n.cirurgias), 0, n.cirurgias)) %>%  # se quiser substituir os NAs dos períodos de internação sem cirurgias por 0
  relocate(c("Prontuario", "DataInternacao", "DataAlta", "n.cirurgias")) %>%  # se quiser as colunas na mesma ordem de movimentacoes
  arrange(Prontuario, DataInternacao)  # se quiser ordenar as linhas

resultado
#>   Prontuario DataInternacao   DataAlta n.cirurgias
#> 1      50000     2016-09-29 2016-09-30           1
#> 2      50000     2017-08-08 2017-08-09           0
#> 3      50000     2017-09-05 2017-09-11           2
#> 4      50000     2018-05-21 2018-05-24           0
#> 5      61111     2016-10-18 2016-10-29           1
#> 6      61111     2017-03-14 2017-04-01           3
#> 7      61111     2018-06-21 2018-07-02           0
```

### Com data.table

Potencialmente mais eficiente do que usar *dplyr* para bases de dados muito grandes (não necessariamente mais rápido, mas com menor uso de memória).

Aqui usei *rolling join*, para tirar proveito da indexação interna de *data.tables* com chaves. Os dados precisam estar ordenados e faz diferença usar `DataInternacao` ou `DataAlta`, dependendo da direção da rolagem.

```
library(data.table)

# Seta como data.table e define chaves (ordena e indexa):
setDT(movimentacoes, key = c("Prontuario", "DataInternacao", "DataAlta"))
setDT(cirurgias, key = c("Prontuario", "DataCirurgia"))

resultado <- movimentacoes[cirurgias, roll = TRUE][
  , .(n.cirurgias = .N), .(Prontuario, DataAlta)][
  movimentacoes, on = .(Prontuario, DataAlta)]

# Muda ordem das colunas
setcolorder(resultado, c("Prontuario", "DataInternacao", "DataAlta", "n.cirurgias"))

# Substitui NAs por 0
resultado[is.na(n.cirurgias), n.cirurgias := 0]

resultado
#>    Prontuario DataInternacao   DataAlta n.cirurgias
#> 1:      50000     2016-09-29 2016-09-30           1
#> 2:      50000     2017-08-08 2017-08-09           0
#> 3:      50000     2017-09-05 2017-09-11           2
#> 4:      50000     2018-05-21 2018-05-24           0
#> 5:      61111     2016-10-18 2016-10-29           1
#> 6:      61111     2017-03-14 2017-04-01           3
#> 7:      61111     2018-06-21 2018-07-02           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está uma maneira em SQL com o pacote `sqldf`.

```r
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite

# primeiro transformar as data/hora em data só
tmp <- movimentacoes
tmp$DataInternacao <- as.Date(tmp$DataInternacao)
tmp$HoraAlta <- as.Date(tmp$HoraAlta)

# fazer o join
sql <- "
select 
  tmp.Prontuario,
  tmp.DataInternacao DataInternacao,
  tmp.HoraAlta HoraAlta,
  cirurgias.data_realiza data_realiza
from tmp, cirurgias
where tmp.Prontuario = cirurgias.prontuario
  and data_realiza between DataInternacao and HoraAlta"

sqldf(sql)
#>   Prontuario DataInternacao   HoraAlta data_realiza
#> 1      50000     2016-09-29 2016-09-30   2016-09-29
#> 2      50000     2017-09-05 2017-09-11   2017-09-07
#> 3      50000     2017-09-05 2017-09-11   2017-09-11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>